# How to increase UITableViewCell based on UIImage inside content

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiimage

I've got problem is how can I increase UITableViewCell based on UIImage inside content.

Image from URL will be downloaded and display inside UIImageView with AlamofireImage.

I've added as follow:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
}
```

and configure right constraint like that

[image]

Please let me know where I'm missed.

Comment: possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18746929/using-auto-layout-in-uitableview-for-dynamic-cell-layouts-variable-row-heights

Comment: set image to top, bottom,left & right contraints & also set image view content mode to aspect fit ,clipstobounds true

Comment: @UmaMadhavi done but not working

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47030491/5362916 check this one

Comment: are you downloading images or loading them locally?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using Auto Layout in UITableView for dynamic cell layouts & variable row heights](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18746929/using-auto-layout-in-uitableview-for-dynamic-cell-layouts-variable-row-heights)

Comment: @Scriptable downloading images from URL with alamofireimage.

Comment: I have had to reload cells once image is downloaded and cached for cells to resize. usually using `reloadRowsAtIndexPaths: [indexPath]`

Comment: @Scriptable any example?