# Dynamic Table Image View in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, tableview, swift4

I have a very similar question as posted here ([Dynamic UIImageView Size Within UITableView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32281886/dynamic-uiimageview-size-within-uitableview)) where I'm trying to dynamically retrieve an image from Firebase and make the resulting tableview adjust to the height of the image given a fixed width across the screen based on the aspect ratio. All the articles I read says to make the cell calculation based on cellforRowAt, but my actual image is within the TableViewCell. Can someone please help?

Tableview controller:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "FeedTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! FeedTableViewCell

    cell.configureCell(post: postArray[indexPath.row])

    return cell
}
```

TableViewCell:

```
func configureCell(post: Post){

   self.postImage.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: post.postImageURL), 
    placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "default"))
}
```

Comment: use Disptach.main.asyn{cell. postImage.kf.setImage(with: URL) { _, _, _, _ in
    cell.layoutIfNeeded()
} }

Answer (score 0):

you have `cell.setNeedsLayout()` inside the completion handler of setting image method, like this:

```
cell. postImage.kf.setImage(with: URL) { _, _, _, _ in
    cell.layoutIfNeeded()
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. Where does that code go? My image is in tableviewcell

Comment: you have to layout cell after it download  inside the completion handler `self.postImage.sd_setImage`

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to use Autolayout to calculate the proper cell height by creating a proper set of constraints that would determine the cell height based on content. I am going to assume you did that.

Then you have to tell the `tableView` you want it to use Autolayout to calculate height:

```
// my best estimation of the height
tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 144
// but the real height is calculated by autolayout
tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
```

Now this would work if the autolayout could calculate the height correctly in `cellForRowAt`. But since the image is downloaded asynchronously, the image is set later, when the cell may be already presented. This requires you to provide a way in which a cell can tell the `tableView` that it has downloaded its content and its layout needs to be recalculated. To do so, use this method in the `viewController` with the `tableView`:

```
func recalculateTableViewLayout() {
    self.tableView.beginUpdates()
    self.tableView.setNeedsLayout()
    self.tableView.endUpdates()
}
```

You will need to pass the reference to the `viewController` with the `tableView` to each cell (I recommend to use delegate pattern for that, here for brevity I will simply sketch it using it directly):

```
class FeedTableViewCell: UITableViewCell { 
    weak var feedViewController: FeedViewController?
    // etc.
```

And in the `cellForRowAt`:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "FeedTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! FeedTableViewCell

    cell.feedViewController = self
    cell.configureCell(post: postArray[indexPath.row])

    return cell
}
```

Then use completion handler of `sd_setImage` to tell the `tableView` to recalculate its layout when the image gets downloaded:

```
func configureCell(post: Post){
    self.postImage.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: post.postImageURL), placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "default")) { (image, error, cache, url) in
        self.feedViewController?.recalculateTableViewLayout()
    }
}
```

Comment: Does it matter that my self.postImage.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: post.postImageURL) is currently located in my tableviewcell file, not tableviewcontroller?