# UITableViewCell Height Issue

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm actually trying to make the image view height dynamic

I have tried `UITableViewAutomaticDimension`

in the cell class I have set the image's dynamic height  based on the aspect constraint

Comment: Can you show us what you tried so far in your code and constraints?

Comment: I have tried UITableViewAutomaticDimension the image is showing with dynamic height as expected but the cell height is not getting updated @Teetz

Comment: post your code please

Comment: I guess we need some more informations in order to help you. Show some of your ViewController's code and some constraints you set.

Comment: I have posted the code.

Comment: There is some confusing stuff going on here. I will cover just a few (only ViewController): 
1. Instead of using `dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier:)` you should use `dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier:for:)` in `cellForRowAt`
2. Why are you returning `UITableViewCell()` in `cellForRowAt`?
3. You don't need to implement `tableView:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath:` - this is not how dynamic height works.

Comment: I have multiple cell types in my cellforrow (just posted a purticular cell's code only)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you can't achieve the dynamic height of cell with **UITableViewAutomaticDimension** on the basis of image's constraints.

**BUT** image's height and width can help you in this. There is a plenty of help regarding this issue is available in following answer:

[Dynamic UIImageView Size Within UITableView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32281886/dynamic-uiimageview-size-within-uitableview)

Comment: My image is actually rendered in the expected way. I need my cell to be dynamic height

Comment: In your cellForRow() method, why are you returning UITableViewCell()? I think you should return your cell instance i.e. cell.

Comment: I have multiple cell types in my cellforrow (just posted a purticular cell's code only)

Answer (score 0):

1. make sure you have set top-bottom constraints in storyboard.
2. save the thumbnail image as data to local storage (I'm using core data)
3. using the thumb image, calculate the aspect of the image
4. customise the row height as you want in `heightForRowAt` method.

```
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        let entity = self.fetchedResultController.object(at: indexPath as IndexPath) as! Message
        var newh:CGFloat = 100.00

        if let fileThumbnails =  entity.file_thumbnails as? NSArray{
            if fileThumbnails.count != 0{
                fileThumbnails.map { (thumbNail) in
                    newh = self.getImageHeight(image:UIImage(data: thumbNail as! Data)! , h: UIImage(data: thumbNail as! Data)!.size.height , w: UIImage(data: thumbNail as! Data)!.size.width)
                }

            }

        }

        if entity.fileStatus == "DeletedMedia" {
            newh = 100
        }
        if entity.fileStatus == nil{
            newh = 0.0
        }
        print ("newH " , newh)
        return newh
    }
    func getImageHeight(image : UIImage, h : CGFloat, w : CGFloat) -> CGFloat {
        let aspect = image.size.width / image.size.height
        var newH = (messagesTV.frame.size.width * 0.6) / aspect
        // customise as you want in newH
        if(newH > 500){
            newH = 500
           //maximum height 500
        }
        if(newH < 100){
            newH = 100
            //minimum height = 100
        }
        return newH
    }
```

if the thumb image is deleted in local storage then a placeholder image will be shown.
you can customise the `newH`variable to get the desired output