# tableView cell dynamic height only works properly after some scrolling

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, height

I'm trying to set the height of my tableview cell based on the height of an image inside my cell, the cell is rendering properly if I scroll a little up and down otherwise it is not getting updated, I have set all necessary constraint the image view (leading, trailing, top, bottom).

and i'm setting the image in my cellforrowat
I have set rowHeight as `UITableViewAutomaticDimension`

I have tried these solution
1. [aspect constraint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32281886/dynamic-uiimageview-size-within-uitableview)
2. [dynamic cell height scrolling issues solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25971147/uitableview-dynamic-cell-heights-only-correct-after-some-scrolling)

Comment: please try Your bottom constrain do greater then equal to instead of equal to.

Comment: you need to let tableview know about changes in your cell layout, this should be mentioned somewhere among answers to these linked questions,  but you should call tableView.beginUpdates()/tableView.endUpdates() for this.

Comment: @FazalrahmanPuliyanchali after changing height of your cell, like you load an image, update cell layout so that image would fit in it and then you tell your table to update.

Comment: Are there any constraints which is failing while your cell is created? Can you please share them?

Comment: can you show me your cell XIB along with constraints. Also do you load the image async from backend?

Comment: No, I need time to try it out and see what is not working

Comment: Hii not the height constrain bottom constrain of UIImageView ?

Comment: which image have bottom constrain of cell that one.

Comment: okay please don't add beginUpdates() and endUpdates().

Comment: @FazalrahmanPuliyanchali as I already mentioned you need to update table after you updated cell layout not in viewDidLoad, or any other unrelated place.

Answer (score 0):

1. make sure you have set top-bottom constraints in storyboard.
2. save the thumbnail image as data to local storage (I'm using core data)
3. using the thumb image, calculate the aspect of the image
4. customise the row height as you want in heightForRowAt method.

I have answer this here:https://stackoverflow.com/a/61768782/7514688